# Nextjs does not load tailwind css classes without re-building everytime

Tags: css, reactjs, next.js, tailwind-css

I am using tailwind css in my nextjs project, and have achieved quite so far, though i am facing an issue which is that when i change the tailwind inbuilt className from "bg-fuchsia-600" to "bg-fuchsia-100", the css class doesnt gets applied, but when i run the script

```
"build-css": "tailwindcss build src/styles/global.css -o public/styles.css"
```

then the css gets applied, so everytime i change the tailwind inbuilt css class , i have to run this script which shouldnt be the case.

Below is the setup for this

global.css

```
@import "tailwindcss/base";
  
@import "tailwindcss/components"; 
 
@import "tailwindcss/utilities";
```

button.css - My custom css file

```
.button{
    color: orange
}
```

the script extracts file in public folder by the name styles.css

and there i created the main.css file with the following content

```
@import './styles.css';
@import '../src/styles/button.css';
```

and then i am using it in the main _app.tsx file

```
import '../public/main.css'
```

Now when i render my component

```
const Login: React.FC<IProps> = (props) => {
  const formik: FormikProps<FormValues> = useFormik<FormValues>({
    initialValues: {
      email: "",
      password: "",
    },
    validationSchema: null,
    onSubmit: (values) => {
      console.log(values);
    },
  });
  return (
    <>
    <p className="bg-fuchsia-100 button">hello</p>
      <Navbar />
    </>
  );
};

export default Login;
```

for the ***P*** tag, the className "button" which is my custom css, the change is reflected in the browser ,but for the tailwind inbuilt classname bg-fuchsia-100 i had to run the script again to make it working if i change it to bh-fuchsia-500 or anything

tailwind.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  content: [
    "./pages/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}",
    "./components/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}",
  ],
  theme: {
    extend: {
      colors: {
        primary: "#fff",
      },
    },
  },
  plugins: [],
};
```

Comment: Tailwind doesn't "watch" for changes by default, so I believe what you're describing is expected behaviour. If you'd like to see Tailwind regenerate your CSS with each file change, you can [integrate it with your build tools](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/installation/using-postcss) or use Tailwind CLI's `--watch` argument.

Comment: but this only happens for some of the classes i suppos, chaging the font-size reflects automatically but changing the color does not, so not sure if this is expected :/

Comment: @George found it, creting a .env file with TAILWIND_MODE=watch fixed the issue